# Fanless laptop, preferably AMD APU-powered

Tags: laptop, fanless

I'm looking to buy a new laptop where performance isn't of a large consideration provided the internals are of the current or last gen (as of 2015). As such, I'd like to go for fanless laptops that are trickling in here and there. I've heard of Intel systems, but would prefer AMD.

Comment: USA or what? AMD Carrizo laptops are currently only available in USA (mostly from HP).

Comment: @Nemo Not USA, but could I've the details? Something could be managed through the gray market.

Comment: I mean things like http://www.notebookcheck.net/HP-Pavilion-17-g054ng-Notebook-Review.147794.0.html . They mention a very low heat; it's also easy to downclock Carrizo AFAIK. However so far there is not much on the market, let alone niche products like fanless solutions... http://www.pcworld.com/article/2870794/amds-carrizo-chip-promises-aggressive-power-savings-but-not-fanless-pcs.html

Comment: @Nemo I still think I've seen some mentioned somewhere... but regardless, AMD APUs are "preferable" not the absolute bottom line. Speaking of fanless Intel, Surfaces come to mind.

Comment: As you may or may not know, AMD CPU's tend to run pretty hot, running it fanless might just turn it into a oven.

Comment: What is your budget anyways?

Comment: @Peter, budget still undecided—I just want a fanless system.

Comment: What are your requirements?

Comment: @Alpha3031, any current/last-gen system will do, hence it's unmentioned in the question.

Comment: @Oxwivi So what do you plan on doing with it? A usage case would be nice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The HP Stream 14 uses the A4 Micro-6400T APU, which is passively cooled. It is already discontinued, but it can still be found on some sites. It is quite limited in performance and storage, but it is the only one passive AMD laptop I have found (and I have been looking for quite a while).